# AngularJS service update controller variable

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular service set up like -

```
function updateViewService($http, $interval) {
var change = true;
var grabTimeStamp = function(){
    $http.get('someapi').then(function success(response){
        //some logic to change var change according to the response
}
$interval(grabTimeStamp, 10000);
return { refresh: function(){
        return change;
    }};
}
```

Now what I need to do is return `change` in controller and also update the controller variable as soon as service `change` changes.

What I suspect is in the controller, the service return function returns the value only once. So I tried `$interval` in my controller while calling the service, that did not update the controller variable either.

I have a lot of controllers, that is why I made one service that should update all the controllers.

Then I tried `$rootScope.$broadcast` whenever `change` variable changes. Tried to listen to broadcasts in controller with `$scope.$on` but did not work.

```
if(change === true){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('dataChanged',change);
    change = false;
}
```

What should be the ideal way to do this?

Basically what I want to do is-

1. Create a service that makes a request every ten seconds and update the `change` variable (Done)
2. Pass this variable to the controller and update the view (basically make a request to the back-end and get the new data {stuck})

Thanks.

Comment: what error are you getting when you fire the event?

Comment: There are no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to know when change variable inside your service changes value?

You can use `$scope.$watch` for this.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

angular.module('app').service('someService', function ($interval, $q) {
  var change = 0;
  
  $interval(function () {
    $q.resolve(Math.random()) //some promise, maybe from $http, but for sake of simplicity I will use $q.resolve
      .then(function (result) {
        change = result; //setting change to random value
      });
  }, 1000); //changes every second
  
  return {
    getChange: function () {
      return change;
    }
  };
});

angular.module('app').controller('Example', function ($scope, someService) {
  $scope.$watch(someService.getChange, function (change) { ///adding watcher on someService.getChange, it will fire when change changes value
    this.change = change; //setting change to controller here you can put some extra logic
  }.bind(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="Example as Ex">
  {{Ex.change}}
</div>
```

Although event should also work, care to share some example of your code in action (jsfiddle, snippet or anything like that)?

Comment: iirc $scope.$watch take a expression string as first args and the expression should be a property of $scope, just curious is this even work ?

Comment: @HarryLim it can take string, but functions are also accepted. And yes it works, it is fired every time when result of this function changes. Ofc this function is called a lot during $digest cycle, so it should be fairy simple. At best some getter, no heavy logic.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to create a simple polling service. It would make a request with specified interval. Here how I would do it:

```
function updateViewService($http, $timeout) {
  var grabTimeStamp = function(callback) {
    return $http.get('someapi').then(function success(response) {
      //some logic to change var change according to the response
      return response.data;
    });
  }

  var poll = function(action, interval) {
    return $timeout(function() {
      grabTimeStamp()
        .then(action)
        .then(poll.bind(null, action, interval))
    }, interval);
  };

  return {
    grabTimeStamp: grabTimeStamp,
    poll: poll
  }
}

app.factory('dataService', updateViewService);
```

Then you would use it in controller like this:

```
dataService.poll(function(data) {
  $scope.data.push(data);
}, 1000);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/MWBlhJzJUh7UJSCJdfPg?p=info

Answer (score 0):

The solution you provided with the event should work but the service must be injected in the controller infact The service must be instantiated by Angular before the controller.

```
.service(function updateViewService($http, $interval, someService) {
var change = true;
var grabTimeStamp = function(){
$http.get('someapi').then(function success(response){
  //some logic to change var change according to the response
  if(change === true){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('dataChanged',change);
    change = false;
  }
}
$interval(grabTimeStamp, 10000);

})

.controller(function($rootScope, updateViewService){
  $rootScope.$on('dataChanged', function(){
    //do something
  });
})
```